# Pandas: updating values based on value from run time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

df1:

```
Steam   feat
1   some_value
2   some_value
3   some_value
4   some_value
```

I have to update the value in "feat" based on certain condition. For example, 
i have to update the feat as "88" when the steam is "2"
The output should look like this:

final output:

```
Steam      feat
    1   some_value
    2      88
    3   some_value
    4   some_value
```

The issue i have here is that, i have to pass the values "2" and "88" in run time values taken from a different table called df2.

df2:

```
cola    colb

2   88
```

To achieve this, I tried to apply the below code:

```
df1.loc[df1["Steam"] = df2.cola.values, 'feat'] = df2.colb.values
```

However i am getting a "invalid syntax" error

the values of df2.cola.values will look like this

```
array(['2'], dtype=object)
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align indices and map your data. This is one way, which should be efficient if you expect a mapping to exist.

```
df1['feat'] = df1['Steam'].map(df2.set_index('cola')['colb']).fillna(df1['feat'])
```